# Java - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to access Mailchimp API in Java with a library (https://github.com/alexanderwe/bananaj). I am trying to authenticate and am getting the error:

```
sunsecurityprovidercertpathSunCertPathBuilderException
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have tried to install the Mailchimp certificate by doing these steps:

1. Saving the certificate by calling `openssl s_client -connect mailchimp.com:443`
2. Installing the certificate by running `keytool -importcert -file public.cert -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -alias mailchimp` and `keytool -importcert -file public.cert -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\security\cacerts" -alias mailchimp`.
3. Verified that I do see Mailchimp certificate by running `keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\security\cacerts"` and `keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\security\cacerts"`. I am confirming this as the last entry contains `Alias name: mailchimp. Creation date: Nov 17, 2017. Entry type: trustedCertEntry. Owner: CN=mailchimp.com, OU=Product Development, O=ROCKET SCIENCE GROUP, L=Atlanta, ST=Georgia, C=US`

I have tried restarting my computer. I also verified that I don't have any other JDKs and JREs installed on my machine as I only see jdk1.8.0_151 and jre-1.8.0_151 in `C:\Program Files\Java`.

What else can I do?

Comment: debug the SSL connection and ensure you are using the correct certificate in the correct keystore